# CSS transition triggering when default styles are applied on page load

Tags: css, css-transitions, pageload

I'm having an issue when CSS is applied on page load.  It's a bit like a **F**lash **O**f **U**nstyled **C**ontent, but all of the elements without a `transition: all .4s ease` style applied show up as expected.  When the page is loaded without caching, it seems as if the transition is applied before the default style is set on that element.

For example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#link" class="foo">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    font: 14px/1.231 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a.foo {
    transition: all .4s ease;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

In this instance, I typically see a gray 18px link on page load.  But some way the page or styles are loading is causing the link to start as a blue 14px link, then animating to the style applied with the `foo` class, gray and 18px.

What would cause this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `transition:all` is usually overkill. You should only apply transitions to those properties you want transitioned.

Comment: I had a case where a stylesheet loaded and placed in the head via JavaScript was the issue. JavaScript (especially when deferred) is applied to late here

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove font-size from the body of your style and size the fonts as you like per element of your dom.

If you size up font on body the first the css rule will be applied to every element and after the browser renders the next rules and so on.

Comment: I agree.  Though that wouldn't explain why my link _transitions_ from the browser's default blue to the `#333` that I've specified in my class.

Comment: Regarding the color issue, ithink something else on your code is wrong. That code you provided isn't having this issue on me when i'm testing on my pc. Could you please share your code? I'll update my answer then.